# How can the max-flow and min-cut problems, if dual to one another, both have unbounded optimal value?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

The **max-flow min-cut theorem** states that the value of the maximum flow is equal to the minimum cut capacity.

It is possible that the max-flow and min-cut is equal to $\infty$.

However, reading **Introduction to Linear Optimization by Bertsimas and Tsitsiklis**, I get the impression that the max-flow and min-cut problems are dual to one another.

From duality theory, I know that, if the primal has finite optimal value then the dual has finite optimal value. Also, if the primal has **unbounded** optimal value, then the dual is infeasible and vice versa.

In the case of the max-flow and min-cut problems, how can they both have **unbounded** optimal value ??

Comment: "It is possible that the max-flow and min-cut is equal to ∞." -- how?

Comment: If all capacities are equal to $\infty$

Comment: If you want to consider this an instance of the network flow problem, okay. Then clearly there are unbounded max-flow and min-cut. You already state that, as a consequence, the two problems can not be dual so your "impression" must be wrong.

Comment: Write out the primal in canonical form with no capacity constraints. Take the dual and see what you get...

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of this anomaly in linear programs:

$$
\begin{align*}
& \max x & & \min \infty y \\
s.t.\; & x \leq \infty & s.t.\; & y \geq 1 \\
& x \geq 0 & & y \geq 0
\end{align*}
$$

The solution to both programs is $\infty$. What goes wrong?

The duality theorem only works when all coefficients are finite. If you go through a proof of the duality theorem you'll see exactly where it fails, and this is a nice exercise.

I should also stress that $\infty$ isn't usually regarded as a legitimate number in these contexts. If we assume all coefficients are real numbers, then $\infty$ is nothing else than a *type mismatch*.

Comment: Aha ! So it goes wrong because we have entries with value $\infty$ for our linear program, but duality is valid only for linear pogram with real entries ?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.